# custom post data - how to

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, customization, excerpt

We're setting up a site to showcase a series of archival recordings. We have the custom post types sorted out thanks to all the help from this site (many, many thanks):

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_radiotalks' );

function create_radiotalks() {
register_post_type( 'radiotalks',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Radio Talks' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Radio Talk' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Add New' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Radio Talk' ),
        'edit' => __( 'Edit' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Radio Talk' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New Radio Talk' ),
        'view' => __( 'View Radio Talk' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View Radio Talk' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Radio Talks' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'No radio talks found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No radio talks found in Trash' ),
        'parent' => __( 'Parent Radio Talk' ),

),
        'public' => true,
        'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
    )
);
}
```

(I think my syntax is correct, but I'll take any critiques:)
It turns out we want to add some more info to each of the individual custom posts. Namely, we'd like to make use of excerpts and custom fields--they aren't showing up on the 'add new radio talk' entry. I've dabbled a bit w/the supports tag, but no luck so far.

Additionally, we'd like to enter a recording ID#, total run time (TRT), # of CDs per set and year of recording for each entry. Is the best approach to register custom taxonomies for this data? Or does it make more sense to make use of custom-fields?

Thanks in advance for all your help..

Don.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add supports to your array like so

```
'supports' => array('title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','comments')
```

As for the additional data per each recording if you need to filter or search by it the create a custom taxonomy if not then a custom fields would be just fine.

Answer (score 2):

To have custom fields available you can either add a
`'supports' => array('custom-fields',"excerpts", "title", "author", etc)`
to your register array, or use
`add_post_type_support( $post_type, $feature )`

[Codex Page for add_post_type_support()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_type_support)

For the additional items you've mentioned, my inclination would be to store them as custom fields and not custom taxonomies